# knockout: can't access parent scoped property from nested foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to access a root level property from within my nested foreach.

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: items, 'as': 'item' } -->
<tr data-bind="foreach: { data: $parent.columns, 'as': 'column' }" >
  <td>{{ item[column.key]  }}</td>
    <!-- ko if: $root.thing -->
    <td><button class="btn btn-default" >click me</button></td>
    <!-- /ko -->            
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

`thing` is a plain object, not an observable. `$root.thing` is evaluating as false. I've also tried `$parent[1].thing`. That gives me a binding error `Message: Cannot read property 'thing' of undefined`, which is weird because I thought `$root` and `$parent[1]` were equivalent in this case.

EDIT: This code is part of a component. In the view it looks something like this:

```
<component data-bind="thing: {prop: 'foo'}, stuff: $data" />
```

In the component, we have:

```
return function(params) {
    this.thing = params.thing;
    this.items = params.stuff.items;
    this.columns = [{key: 'one'}, {key: 'two'}];
})
```

Comment: It should be `$parents[1]` which is equivalent to root. Though this might not answer to your problem because `$parents[1].thing` is still false. Showing more code (but not all) like your viewmodel will be helpful.

Comment: Actually, `$parents[1].thing` works, but I'd still like to know why `$root` isn't working. Is it because it's a component?

Comment: Oh, I see so this is from a component, well `$root` will not work because it will look at the root variables of your viewmodel.

Comment: Yes, and I can use $component as of knockout 3.3.

Comment: Yup, $component is the $root equivalent in the if you are within the context of a particular component template. But i want to comment on your answer, `$root` works on a component, it just wont look at the base variables of the component, rather it will look at the member variables in the view model, the model that you passed in the applyBindings.

Answer (score 0):

`$root` references the viewmodel, not the component, use `$parents[]`. As of knockout 3.3, you can also use `$component`.